# Сортировка многомерного массива по времени

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [150] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 10:00:00
                    [TIME] => 2000
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 2:20:00
                    [TIME] => 3000
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 05:15:00
                    [TIME] => 5000
                )

        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 7:00:00
                    [TIME] => 500
                )

            [50] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 5:00:00
                    [TIME] => 600
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 3:00:00
                    [TIME] => 200
                )

        )

)
```

Нужно отсортировать второй уровень массива по полю TIME_LEFT, чтобы получилось так:

```
Array
(
    [150] => Array
        (    
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 2:20:00
                    [TIME] => 3000
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 05:15:00
                    [TIME] => 5000
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 10:00:00
                    [TIME] => 2000
                )
        )

    [100] => Array
        (    
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 3:00:00
                    [TIME] => 200
                )

            [50] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 5:00:00
                    [TIME] => 600
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [TIME_LEFT] => 7:00:00
                    [TIME] => 500
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Проходим по всем элементам и каждый сортируем usort:

```
$array[150] =  array(5 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"10:00:00","TIME"=>2000),
                    20 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"2:20:00","TIME"=>3000),
                    10 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"05:15:00","TIME"=>5000));


$array[100] =  array(11 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"7:00:00","TIME"=>500),
                    50 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"5:00:00","TIME"=>600),
                    7 =>array("TIME_LEFT"=>"3:00:00","TIME"=>200));

foreach ($array as &$value) {
       usort($value, function($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a['TIME_LEFT']) <=> strtotime($b['TIME_LEFT']);
       });

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо